# How to authenticate and GET search tweet using Twitter API 1.1?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Twitter has implemented Authentication in their API version 1.1. Now how can i search tweets using a keyword with Authentication in Java ?
I tried to use the code given [Here](http://www.coderslexicon.com/demo-of-twitter-application-only-oauth-authentication-using-java/) to authenticate. But i am getting "Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=freebandnames"

Can anyone help me out

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: Are you authenticated? Have you obtained Oauth credentials for some user and are you using those with the request?